# Como fazer um update em uma tabela percorrendo uma outra tabela em Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Eu tenho um esquema segundo a foto abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O objetivo é fazer um update de valores da coluna seller_comission na tabela tbl_history. A tabela tbl_history já possui alguns milhares de registros. A comissão do vendendor é diferente para cada produto e o valor está registrado na tabela tbl_plans. A tabela tbl_prod_plan guarda a relação dos planos e os produtos.

Poderia fazer loops com php e resolveria o problema. Mas a pergunta é como poderia ser feito esse update só usando sql. A base de dados é MySql.

Comment: Não entendi nada...

Comment: Não entendi nada...²

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua modelagem está um tanto quanto confusa, porém se você quiser fazer um `UPDATE` com base em outra tabela, basta utilizar a cláusula `FROM` com alias e `JOIN`, em conjunto com o `GROUP BY` por código de produto e `SUM` para conseguir a somatória total da coluna da outra tabela:

```
UPDATE th
   SET th.seller_comission = SUM(tp.seller_comission)
  FROM tbl_history th
       INNER JOIN tbl_prod_plan tpp ON tpp.prod = th.prod
       INNER JOIN tbl_plans tp ON tp.id = tpp.id_plan
 GROUP BY th.prod
```

Comment: Usei uma variação da sua resposta e funcionou. `UPDATE history AS th 
INNER JOIN tbl_prod_plan AS tpm ON LOWER(tpm.prod) = LOWER(th.prod) 
INNER JOIN tbl_plans AS tp ON tp.id = tpm.id
SET th.seller_commission = tp.seller_commission;`

Comment: @zwitterion Beleza. Se a resposta lhe atendeu não esqueça de marcá-la como escolhida para que outras pessoas com dúvida similar possam se beneficiar da resposta.

Comment: Nota, está meio confuso pq não estou usando os campos reais e na totalidade. O modelo tem cerca de 200 tabelas e muitas delas possuem em média 25 campos. Usei somente os campos que julguei importantes para a pergunta.  E outra coisa, nessa empresa é proibido usar primary key. Uma particularidade que não faz parte da pergunta mas pode dificultar  a idéia geral.

Comment: @zwitterion só por curiosidade: qual o motivo pelo qual é proibido utilizar `primary key`?

Comment: Não tem nenhum motivo técnico (ao meu ver). Eles temem alguém deletar 1 registro por acidente e sair deletando em cascata. Isso é o que pensa o CTO da empresa. Por isso é proibido usar PK nas relações da tabela.